# OneToOne Association In JPA not working using Spring boot and spring data JPA

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, model-associations

I am trying to implement the OneToOne association in JPA and trying to join two tables using spring boot and spring data JPA. I created one spring boot microservice and implemented the one to one association in my model. But when I am running code I am getting the following error ,

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElement
```

Here My First model class Users.java is like following,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 9178661439383356177L;

@Id

@Column(name="user_id")
public Integer userId;

@Column(name="username")
public String username;

@Column(name="password")
public String password;


}
```

And I am testing association by controller using following code,

```
@GetMapping("/load")
    public Users load() {
        return (Users) userObj.findAll();
    }
```

Can anyone help to resolve this association issue please ?

Comment: What documentation told you that having `@OneToMany` on a single valued field of type `Users` is correct?

Comment: What documentation told you that having `@OneToOne` on a multi valued field of type `List` is correct?

Comment: Its not multivalued type. Check my updated question please.

Comment: The error message says clearly `@OneToMany` and you had a `OneToMany` before changing your question. And now you don't have one. And now the error message is not relevant to the question. So if you are going to rewrite questions open a new question rather than deeming all responses redundant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong.

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="nuserId")
public Set<UserRoleMapping> roleUserRoleMappingMappingJoin;
}
```

OneToOne means only one object..right?

See this for mappings understandings.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-persistent

Comment: Yes. For each user in users table is mapped to only one entry in userrolemapping table. So here I thought that one to one mapping. Did you got my association that how I am thinking . Please let me know if I went in wrong direction.

Comment: looks like you want to use manytomany so that 3rd table will be automatically will get created if mapping and mappedBy is correct.let mappings handle everything.see this https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-many-to-many

Answer (score 0):

Annotation @OneToOne defines a single-valued association to another entity, and in your case you associate a user to a Set of UserRoleMapping instead of associating it with a single object of that class. Use @ManyToOne annotation

Comment: No. for each user record in user have the corresponding record in userrolemapping . So I am thought that this is a one to one mapping.Please letme know If I went wrong. Thank you for your response.

Comment: if he uses manytoone also public Set<UserRoleMapping> roleUserRoleMappingMappingJoin; this will be wrong as for manytoone also we should have single object only.

Comment: If each user has a unique record in UserRoleMapping, then why you use Set? As far as I understand from the table name, it is an association for users and roles in a different table, and in this case you need to use @ManyToMany

Answer (score 0):

Actually the exception refers to an invalid  `@OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElement` mapping

and this can only be

```
@OneToMany()
@JoinColumn(name="nuser_id" , referencedColumnName="nuserId")
public Users nuserId;
```

If the `@OneToMany` relation is valid change this at first to

```
@OneToMany()
@JoinColumn(name="nuser_id" , referencedColumnName="nuserId")
public List<Users> users;
```

If the `@OneToMany` relation is **NOT** valid change this to

```
@OneToOne()
@JoinColumn(name="nuser_id" , referencedColumnName="nuserId")
public Users users;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response sir. But I still doubt with this one to many. Because each record in users have corresponding record in userrolemapping. Not many. So how it would be one to many ? I did not understood your point?

Comment: You have one role that is associated to many Users. E.g. ONE Role 'User' will possibly have MANY users.

Comment: No. In my case I am uses multi tenant model application. In one tenant one user only have one role. May have different , but in another tenant only. Not in same.And I have separate separate DB for each tenant. Here only possibility is one record is only mappes to one record in userrolemapping. I hope that what I am trying to say. Please let me know sir,

Comment: My answer is about your exception and not a consulting to your technical problems/ questions. See my updated answer.